# Scaleout webhooks registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, webhooks, asp.net-webhooks

I have an application distributed in this folliwing architecture:

Architecture:
[image]

2 Sender and 2 Receivers (each is a self-host service) that communicate through WebHook Custom registration. In the middle from this service there is a Load Balancer.
A Sender can also manage post requests coming from external clients, then it will notify to registered Receivers.
When a process of a Receiver starts, it sends a request of subscription to the Sender.
With the presence of a Load Balancer I can't register a Receiver at the same moment in the 2 Senders.

So my doubt is:

If a subscription request goes through a Load Balancer, how can I register the same request to the 2 Sender too at the same time?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly i have one question: Why do you want to register the receiver to both senders?

Comment: Because  I need to send a gossip request from another client and at the same time Senders must notify it in real-time. When a Receive subscribes a registration I don’t know where it will be managed the subscription ( on the Sender 1 or Sender 2). Same thing for a “gossip” request.

Comment: So a receiver (client) needs to be able to send a gossip request and the senders then need to notify all the receivers of this? I'm sorry but I'm having a really difficult time understanding your English

Comment: I'm sorry, I try to explain me better.

Comment: Look at the picture.

For example, I send a "gossip" request from my Client Manager to Sender 1 or Sender 2 ( it depends on the Load Balancer). Imagine Sender 1.
Meantime a Receiver client sends a subscription to the Sender 2.  
If my "gossip" request goes to the Sender 1 but my Receiver has been subscribed to Sender 2, it won't be able to receive the notification. 
Is it clear now?

Comment: Is the Client Request Manager the only one that can send gossip requests?

Comment: Yes it is the only one can send gossip requests

Comment: So if the Client Request Manager is the only one that can send gossip requests and those gossip requests need to make it to every Sender, there are multiple ways I see right now to fix this. 1) Make the Load Balancer recognize the Client Request Manager and send the Request to every Sender, 2) Connect the Client Request Manager to every Sender and send the gossip request directly or 3) Make the Senders synchronise the Gossip Requests they get with each other

Comment: Ok thanks. Maybe I try the solution #3